# Custom Collection View Cell with alternate cell styles

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to customize collection view cell to display item as shown below. Assume that number of items in the datasource to be 10

```
cell1        cell6
cell2        cell7
cell3        cell8
cell4        cell9
cell5        cell10
```

can anyone please help me to achieve this. Thank You

Comment: If you need two different custom cells, take two prototype cells with both having different identifiers and deque them accordingly in your cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: I am using only single cell. This approach I am using only for ipad. for iphone it is like continuous like tableview

Comment: The cells can't be placed like that. But the data which you are going to display in cell can be conditioned to fill according to your needs. You won't find any difference, just need to be cautious while accessing

Comment: Ok Thanks Harsha :) Can You Please share the logic